# Android studio loading wrong project

Tags: android-studio-3.4

I have Two projects sharing my library project in same directory like this

```
Project 1
  app/
  ../Library Project/library/
Project 2
  app/
  ../Library Project/library/
Library Project
  library
```

Now when I project 1 it works fine , let's say now I have to work on Project 2 then it loads Project 1 instead of Project 2. Now if I delete the .idea directory of Project 2 , it works fine. But when I open Project 1 again it does same and loads Project 2 instead of Project 1.
 Is there any permanent solution for this problem ?